# How to increase the size of /dev/sda2 in SUSE running on VMware?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, vmware, suse

How can I increase the size of the `/dev/sda2` partition?

`df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       7.0G  3.7G  3.0G  56% /
devtmpfs        432M  172K  432M   1% /dev
tmpfs           432M     0  432M   0% /dev/shm
IOInterceptor   7.0G  3.7G  3.0G  56% /primary/iointerceptor/mountdir
```

`fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders, total 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007c01d

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     2056191     1027072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2   *     2056192    16777215     7360512   83  Linux
```

I've also edited the virtual machine settings to change the hard disk size from 8 GB (initially allocated) to 40 GB. Now how should I increase the size of the above mentioned partition? I searched over Google but haven't found how to do this.

**EDIT:**

Created new partition `/dev/sda3`. `fdisk -l` after creating new partition:

```
/dev/sda1            2048     2056191     1027072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2   *     2056192    16777215     7360512   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        16777216    41943039    12582912   83  Linux
```

But when I used `resize2fs /dev/sda3` it showed the below error:

```
resize2fs 1.41.9 (22-Aug-2009)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda3
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you have `parted` version 3.2, then run `parted /dev/sda` and use the `resizepart` command to resize sda2, moving the end of the partition to the end of the disk.  Then run `resize2fs /dev/sda2` to enlarge the filesystem to use the additional space.  Reboot not required.

Comment: You saved me a ton of time, thank you. By the way, this works for Arch Linux for any Arch users wondering.

Comment: I have parted version 3.3, does it work? I want to increase `/dev/sda2` which is my `swap`.

Comment: I have `/dev/sda1 2048 106745855 106743808 50.9G 83 Linux` and `/dev/sda2       106745856 117229567  10483712    5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris`. Can I do your commands: `parted /dev/sda`, `resizepart`, `resize2fs /dev/sda2`. With `df` I do not see `/dev/sda2`, just `/dev/sda1`.Use in % is 36%, so much space on sda1

Comment: @Timo, if it is sda1 you want to resize, then that is what you will need to resize, not sda2.  Also you don't have any free space to expand sda1 into.

Answer (score 3):

1) Boot this virtual machine from livecd.iso of any distr (example ubuntu)

2) find disk what you want resize (probably /dev/sda)

3) `fdisk /dev/sda
d - remove partition
2 - number partition
n - create new
p - type primary
2 - number
2056192 - start on same block, that started deleted partition
<press enter to save default value> - max avaible size
w - write changes and exit`

4) after that resize you filesystem with `resize2fs /dev/sda2` or other utils (depends your filesystem. resize2fs - for ext2/3/4)

Comment: Hi, I've created new partition /dev/sda3. But when used resize2fs command, it showing error "resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda3
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock."

Comment: Please let me know whats going wrong here?

Comment: You have created new partition /dev/sda3 without filesystems.  But i don`t understand why. You had to create partition with same number that deleted and same offset for first block but large.

Comment: Reed your update. Just `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3`

Comment: I'm new to Linux and dont know these partition and physical volume concepts. I just want increase size /dev/sda2.

Comment: You mean to say i've to delete the existing /dev/sda2 and create new one with same name? data in  /dev/sda2  will be lost right?

Comment: I have writed simple list of commands. Just do them. (after you update: add `d 3` after `d 2`)

Comment: if you recreate partition with same number and offset (thirst block) no data will be loss. But be carefull.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15376/discussion-between-mr-tron-and-pradi).

Answer (score 0):

All commands need in root first `sudo -i`

0. Get the concept from official GNU https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html#SEC30 Being familiar with `parted` and `fdisk`.
1. remove swap. normally it's in `/dev/sda3`. Create another swap at the end disk using 1GB.
2. Make sure that you have `parted` version 3.2, then run `parted /dev/sda` and use the `resizepart` command to resize sda2. It will ask you the partition number. normally it's just the last character of sda2. also could check it with `parted -l`.
3. Moving the end of the partition to the end of the disk but left 1GB for the swap. Then quit from `parted` and run `resize2fs /dev/sda2` to enlarge the filesystem to use the additional space.
4. Suppose to work now. But can also verify it with GUI. There are enlarge options available too. You could try to get some luck from it.
5. Now clean up for boot slow. https://askubuntu.com/a/1305402/1121985

always try using `help` first if got stuck. Don't trust StackOverflow too much as there are different distribution and versions. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

### Pre-check for your disks

First of all, you need to know the status of your disks at beginning. To have a pre-check of your disks, you can use the command: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc` .  The result would be similar like this:

```
wyu@wyu-vm01:~> sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 128 GiB, 137438953472 bytes, 268435456 sectors
Disk model: Virtual Disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 82719DF5-D3FE-4960-A694-DABB4556C3E9

Device     Start       End   Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 134215679 134213632  64G Linux filesystem
```

Use command `df -h` to check the general info of your disks.

```
wyu@wyu-vm01:~> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G   23M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.2G  9.9M  3.2G   1% /run
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb4       127G   45G   83G  35% /
/dev/loop3      583M  583M     0 100% /snap/datagrip/162
/dev/loop4      185M  185M     0 100% /snap/gitkraken/201
/dev/loop2       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1778
/dev/loop0      586M  586M     0 100% /snap/datagrip/163
/dev/loop1       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1738
/dev/loop5      347M  347M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
/dev/loop6      185M  185M     0 100% /snap/gitkraken/202
/dev/loop7       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2667
/dev/loop11     128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop8      347M  347M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
/dev/loop9       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop10      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2654
/dev/loop13     1.2G  1.2G     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/401
/dev/loop12     1.2G  1.2G     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/398
/dev/loop15     744M  744M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/314
/dev/loop14     674M  674M     0 100% /snap/phpstorm/307
/dev/loop16     668M  668M     0 100% /snap/phpstorm/310
/dev/loop17     757M  757M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/316
/dev/loop18     263M  263M     0 100% /snap/redis-desktop-manager/626
/dev/loop19      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17883
/dev/loop20      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17950
/dev/loop22     605M  605M     0 100% /snap/webstorm/294
/dev/loop21     602M  602M     0 100% /snap/webstorm/291
/dev/sdc1        64G   36G   29G  57% /home
/dev/sdb3      1014M   98M  917M  10% /boot
/dev/sdb2       512M  3.0M  509M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   60K  1.6G   1% /run/user/470
/dev/sda1        32G   24K   30G   1% /mnt
tmpfs           1.6G   76K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see above, I need to increase the size of my data disk, from 64G to 128G.

### Increase the size of the data disk on Azure portal

To increase the size of the data disk, the first step is to increase it for my VM on Azure portal.

On the left panel of the Azure portal, click `Disks` and then click the data disk you want to increase.

[image]

Then, click `Size + performance` to choose the new size of your data disk.

[image]

Click "Save" button, the VM will resize your data disk with the new size.

### Make the new size available for your data disk

Unfortunately, OpenSUSE will not automatically increase the file system. So the size will stay the same if you check your data disk. You need to resize file system to make the new free space available for use.

According the document from OpenSUSE ([Resizing File Systems](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/html/SLES-all/cha-resize-fs.html)) , we can use this command to increase the file system: `sudo xfs_growfs -d /dev/sdc1`. However, it did not work for me.

```
meta-data=/dev/sdc1              isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=4194176 blks
         =                       sectsz=4096  attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=0    bigtime=0 inobtcount=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=16776704, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=8191, version=2
         =                       sectsz=4096  sunit=1 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size unchanged, skipping
```

After some research, the reason is that the OS did not expand the partition automatically. So, there was no more free space for the partition to increase. To make it happen, we need to grow the partition first.

For OpenSUSE, we can use `growpart` to grow a partition. The command for the purpose is: `sudo growpart /dev/sdc 1`.

The result of the command shows that the size of the partition is changed.

`CHANGED: partition=1 start=2048 old: size=134213632 end=134215680 new: size=268433375 end=268435423`

Now, let's try to grow the file system with the previous command `sudo xfs_growfs -d /home`:

```
sudo xfs_growfs -d /home
meta-data=/dev/sdc1              isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=4194176 blks
         =                       sectsz=4096  attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=0    bigtime=0 inobtcount=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=16776704, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=8191, version=2
         =                       sectsz=4096  sunit=1 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 16776704 to 33554171
```

It looks great! Let's check the disk by `df -h`:

```
wyu@wyu-vm01:~> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G   23M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.2G  9.9M  3.2G   1% /run
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb4       127G   45G   83G  35% /
/dev/loop3      583M  583M     0 100% /snap/datagrip/162
/dev/loop4      185M  185M     0 100% /snap/gitkraken/201
/dev/loop2       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1778
/dev/loop0      586M  586M     0 100% /snap/datagrip/163
/dev/loop1       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1738
/dev/loop5      347M  347M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
/dev/loop6      185M  185M     0 100% /snap/gitkraken/202
/dev/loop7       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2667
/dev/loop11     128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop8      347M  347M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
/dev/loop9       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop10      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2654
/dev/loop13     1.2G  1.2G     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/401
/dev/loop12     1.2G  1.2G     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/398
/dev/loop15     744M  744M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/314
/dev/loop14     674M  674M     0 100% /snap/phpstorm/307
/dev/loop16     668M  668M     0 100% /snap/phpstorm/310
/dev/loop17     757M  757M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/316
/dev/loop18     263M  263M     0 100% /snap/redis-desktop-manager/626
/dev/loop19      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17883
/dev/loop20      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17950
/dev/loop22     605M  605M     0 100% /snap/webstorm/294
/dev/loop21     602M  602M     0 100% /snap/webstorm/291
/dev/sdc1       128G   36G   92G  29% /home
/dev/sdb3      1014M   98M  917M  10% /boot
/dev/sdb2       512M  3.0M  509M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   60K  1.6G   1% /run/user/470
/dev/sda1        32G   24K   30G   1% /mnt
tmpfs           1.6G   76K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

[image]

As you can see, the size of my data disk increased. I will not be got the issue of disk is full in a short period of time.

Comment: This answer shows how you extended a partition on your VM. It is unclear how this relates to the specific question that is being asked. Consider updating your answer to show how it is relevant to the specific situation presented in the question.